# jquery superscrollorama fixed bgimg

Tags: jquery, html, css, superscrollorama

i need to get a scrolling from several elements. in that case here from the three pictures.

Thats no problem to do that, but what i try to achieve is that during my scrollevent the bg stays the same (more or less fixed) and after the scrollevent is finished the background moves on.

html:

```
<div id="infografik">
    <div id="innerWrapper">
        <div class="minerWrapper">
            <img class="miner1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/infografik/00_miners/Girl_Miner.png" alt="girl miner" />
            <img class="miner2" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/infografik/00_miners/Head_Miner.png" alt="girl miner" />
            <img class="miner3" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/infografik/00_miners/Boy_Miner.png" alt="girl miner" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#infografik{
    font-size:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:url('../images/infografik/whole_bkgd_2.jpg')center center no-repeat;
    height:6200px;
    /*position:fixed;*/
}
#innerWrapper{
    width:935px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0.3;
}
.minerWrapper{
    top:260px;
    position:relative;
}
#scrollwrapper{
    height:6200px;
    position:absolute;
    /*overflow:scroll;*/
}
```

jquery:

```
controller.pin($('#infografik'), 700, {
    anim: (new TimelineLite())
        .append(
            TweenMax.fromTo($('img.startGM'), .45,
                {css:{width: 22}, immediateRender:true},
                {css:{width: 172}})
        ),
    onUnpin: function(){
        $('#infografik').css('position', 'relative');
    }
}, -2000);
```

i have tried to give the bg first fixed position, but after the scroll-event he jumps back to start...

i also tried to give the minerWrapper the fixed position with the superscrollorama pin function but that just causes that the miners stand still during the event, but the background moves on, and i need that everything stands and the scroll-event moves some things.

greetings timmi

I need to h

Answer (score 0):

They Timotheus I know you are just approaching this from the wrong way,  the pin should fix the page to whatever you want so the background isn't going to change.

I would also caution against doing any position changes for the pin,  that is just going to cause some unpredictable things in the DOM.  I would recommend removing all your positioning to start.

From the best I can understand you are trying to do some animation of the 3 images but I can't really get what you are wanting to do.  Anyway you could put this into a JSFiddle or something so I can get a better look?

Answer (score 0):

We can fix it by automatically scroll down when the page loads.

This is the script:

```
function Scrolldown() {
     window.scroll(0,1); 
}
```

Example Links:

http://codepen.io/subin/pen/dprkkY

please let's know your suggestion.